# vert.x setup for high load server

Tags: vert.x

I have server with 8 CORES
In that server I have 3000 incoming requests per second
What settings are best to use for best performance?
**new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(???);**
Do I need 8 instances because of my 8 cores server? By default it's 1.
Is that better to use: **.setWorker(true).setWorkerPoolSize(???)**
Or I need just keep nothing for that? And if I need to set workerPoolSize how much will it be? By default it's 20.

I can't compare it in production, I need predict for that.

Thanks a lot for answer!

And additional question:
Is the following the right way to making async work in vertx pipeline?
pipeline step call function that return **Future** and in that **Future** in **onComplete** will call **ctx.next()**
If no, how I can do async work in the middle of pipeline?

Comment: The only way to accurately answer this is to do benchmarks on your actual application. There are too many variables that affect what settings will work best for anyone to accurately tell you what to use. For your second question, if you're talking about a pipeline of HTTP handlers using `RoutingContext`, then what you described is correct.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In common: should I use 8 instances for 8 core machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have 16 instances for 8 cores.

Are you using the `executeBlocking` functionality? If yes - you should set the worker pool size to 128

> And additional question: Is the following the right way to making async work in vertx pipeline? pipeline step call function that return Future and in that Future in onComplete will call ctx.next() If no, how I can do async work in the middle of pipeline?

Question doesn't make sense. You should read the docs before putting a service that serves 3k rps in production